# How to merge images in VB.net that go beyond the Bitmap capability

Tags: vb.net, image, bitmap

I am trying to merge two images which are rather large in vb.net. My code is as follows

```
 Private Function mergeImages(im1 As Image, im2 As Image, x1 As Integer, x2 As Integer) As Image
    Dim mergedRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, x1 + im2.Width - x2, im1.Height)
    Dim MergedImage = New Bitmap(mergedRect.Width, mergedRect.Height)
    Using grp = Graphics.FromImage(MergedImage)
        grp.DrawImage(im1, New Rectangle(0, 0, x1, im1.Height), New Rectangle(0, 0, x1, im1.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        grp.DrawImage(im2, New Rectangle(x1, 0, im2.Width, im2.Height), New Rectangle(0, 0, im2.Width, im2.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        im1.Dispose()
        im2.Dispose()
        Return MergedImage
    End Using
End Function
```

This code works fine for smaller images but not for large. I know there is a limitation on bitmaps, I would just like to find a way around this limitation, if possible.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How large are you talking?  There are a lot of limits in GDI...

Comment: There are 21 images all up that are 2000px x 20000px. They will all be merged to make 42000px x 20000px

Comment: The limit on the .net bitmap class is 2^15px.  The AForge framework can handle more but I cant find an example.